# xquery equivalent of tsql where clause within XML nodes

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xquery

I'm trying to shred XML files that have an unusual layout, because items are not arranged with conventional elements and attributes, but instead in a kind of "list within the xml" format:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<SOAP-ENV:Body> 
<ns:Lists xmlns:ns="urn:Listing"> 
    <ns:items>
      <ns:listRef>List1</ns:listRef> 
      <ns:name>Test list items</ns:name> 
      <ns:extendedFields>
         <ns:extendedField>
             <ns:name>Fruit</ns:name> 
             <ns:data>Apple</ns:data> 
      </ns:extendedField>
      <ns:extendedField>
             <ns:name>Vegetable</ns:name> 
              <ns:data /> 
      </ns:extendedField>
      <ns:extendedField>
              <ns:name>Sweet</ns:name> 
             <ns:data>Crunchie</ns:data> 
      </ns:extendedField>
    </ns:extendedFields>
    </ns:items>
</ns:Lists>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I've tried variations of the XQuery below, but am not getting it right. What I need to do is the Xpath equivalent of "select ns:data from x where ns:name = 'Fruit'" for example. In the past I was able to do this using singleton numbering to point to the location of the bit that I wanted on the tree, but in this case the number of extendedFields is variable, and the sequence changes, so the only way to get to the node you want will be to specify the name/value pair that you want.

```
DECLARE @x xml 
 SET @x = 
(   SELECT xml_data_column   
   FROM dbo.Table   
 WHERE xmlFileName = 'D:\XML_list.xml'); 

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:Listing' AS ns) 
SELECT t.c.value('../ns:listRef[1]', 'varchar(20)') listRef  
, t.c.value('../ns:name[1]', 'varchar(20)') name  
, t.c.value('/.', 'varchar(30)') ext1b
, t.c.value('ns:extendedField[1]/ns:name[1]', 'varchar(30)') name1
, t.c.value('ns:extendedField[1]/ns:data[1]', 'varchar(30)') data1
, t.c.value('ns:extendedField[2]/ns:name[1]', 'varchar(30)') name2
, t.c.value('ns:extendedField[2]/ns:data[1]', 'varchar(30)') data2
, t.c.value('ns:extendedField[3]/ns:name[1]', 'varchar(30)') name3
, t.c.value('ns:extendedField[3]/ns:data[1]', 'varchar(30)') data3
FROM  @x.nodes('//ns:Lists/ns:items/ns:extendedFields[1]') AS t(c)
```

So if I wanted to see what fruit item this person opted for, then I would want the output to look like:

```
listRef, name,                Fruit 
List1,   Test list items,   Apple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with xmlnamespaces('urn:Listing' AS ns)
select L.X.value('ns:listRef[1]', 'varchar(20)') as listRef,
       L.X.value('ns:name[1]', 'varchar(20)') as name,
       E.X.value('ns:data[1]', 'varchar(30)') as Fruit
from @x.nodes('//ns:Lists/ns:items') as L(X)
  cross apply L.X.nodes('ns:extendedFields/ns:extendedField[ns:name = "Fruit"]') as E(X)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Mikael. That works 100%, and I see I can extend the field list by just adding cross applies at the bottom. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Follow-up question: I've been using the above for over a year without a single issue. But now upgrading to SQL2008 R2, and while testing the script in SSIS it's thrown an error: "The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query." 
I've pinpointed it to one of the selects that has 12 cross applies, so I gather it's not happy with that. Any ideas how I can work around this?

Comment: ...in the meantime I've just split the above into two separate batches, so there are less cross-applies.

Comment: @brynn I have never seen that. If you could post the xml and the query as a question I would be interested to have a look at it. If you do add a question please notify me here with a link to it